# Unichar variable in Swift

Tags: swift, unichar

How to define a `unichar` type variable in Swift likes `'\0'` `'\n'` in Objective-C ?

In Swift,

```
func previousCharacter() -> unichar {
    return "\n"     //Error
}
```

Compiler gave me an error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to expected return type 'unichar'

But in Objective-C, it will more easy to do this directly.

Comment: You do it the same way... But with "" signs. Or if you mean unicode you do like this: "\u{24}"

Comment: @Arbitur  "" signs will be recognized as String type

Comment: Use ***Character*** http://swiftdoc.org/type/Character/

Comment: Does it have to be exactly the unichar type? Do you need it to interface with Objective-C or C code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift, the character literals are of type `Character`.

```
let exclamationMark: Character = "!"
```

See [Strings and Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID285)

**For advanced readers:**

You can also extend `unichar` with the capability to accept character literals:

```
extension unichar : UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible {
    public typealias UnicodeScalarLiteralType = UnicodeScalar

    public init(unicodeScalarLiteral scalar: UnicodeScalar) {
        self.init(scalar.value)
    }
}


let newLine: unichar = "\n"
let whitespaces = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()

print("C is whitespace \(whitespaces.characterIsMember(newLine))")
```

However, note that Swift literals use 4 bytes while `unichar` uses only 2 bytes, therefore some characters will be truncated when converted to `unichar`.

Comment: Beat me to it ... I had originally tried to make an extension on unichar, that defined a convenience initializer. After reading a bit more into the topic: This does not actually require Swift 2.0 and works perfectly fine with current Versions. unichar, which you're extending is not a protocol but a struct ;)

Comment: Furthermore, you can directly use `UnicodeScalar` as your `UnicodeScalarLiteralType` and get rid of the let. All it does is initialize a `UnicodeScalar` with another `UnicodeScalar`. Lastly, you don't need to prefix the value type with `unichar.` typealiases are scoped anyways and even if you had one with the same name declared at the global level, it would pick the one you declared in the extension.

Comment: @TimBodeit Thanks, did update the code. I had a LOT of problems with the compiler crashing so it took me time to come with a valid syntax.

Comment: Should have used a stable Xcode version :P No need for the beta here

Comment: At Swift 5, UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible has been renamed to:
ExpressibleByUnicodeScalarLiteral